# How to get text popups on an image using CSS3 animations?

Tags: css, animation, styling

I'm looking for guidance here:

I have an image of a band about halfway down my page. When the user scrolls to it I'd like the band name to appear on top of it and then each member's heads get circled and their names popup next to each circle.

Hopefully that's clear -- it is in my head at least.

I'm thinking this could be accomplished using CSS animations, but I unsure. There's probably more than one way to skin this cat. Looking to be pointed in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use skrollr: https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr

Comment: I see that you are new to SO. We'll help you fix your code, but we won't do create all for you. Show us what you have tried.